# Unable to connect with SQLPlus, but it works with SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Windows 7, Oracle 11.2.0.1; it used to be working fine, not sure what happened lately.  But I am not able to connect to SQL plus using sqlplus, and entering user name and password.

SQL Developer is working fine.  Also the following command is working fine:

```
sqlplus system/system@//localhost:1521/ORACUSTOM
```

Though the above command is working fine, some of the scripts are not working (as these scripts try to connect to a different database. So I need to make the following work:

```
$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sat Nov 10 19:35:34 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: system
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Enter user-name:
```

I'd appreciate if you can explain why one approach is working and the other is not.

Answer (score 1):

The jdbc connection string

```
sqlplus system/system@//localhost:1521/ORACUSTOM
```

indicates that the service name 'ORACUSTOM' is used as the service name.  Check the tnsnames.ora file for the right TNS name & ensure that it uses 'Oracustom' as the service name

In your case the TNS name should be something like

```
orcl =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = localhost)(Port = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = oracustom)
 )
)
```

With this entry in tnsnames.ora, you'll have to enter `system@orcl` as the username

(PS: [Don't login as system. Bad idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/408/120).)

Comment: my tnsnames are setup correctly.  system@orcl worked fine, but the script was still failing.  The main reason for my issues were, i setup 32bit oracle client and that is causing the issue (Can't load jdbc driver error).  Once i remove the 32bit client references from PATH variable, it started working fine, also with just system as username.

BTW, i am installing a software and I need to login as system user. Thanks for your leads.